# Why foreach and % Acts differently

Tags: powershell

See this Example:

```
$Map = @{
1 = "Id 1"
2 = "Id 2"
3 = "Id 3"
4 = "Id 4"
}

$Ids = 1,2,3,4

foreach ($id in $Ids) {

    if ($Map[$id])
    {
        return $Map[$id]
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Id 1
```

But when using foreach alias `%` the `return` keyword is ignored and the iteration continue

```
$Ids | % {

    if ($Map[$_])
    {
        return $Map[$_]
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Id 1
Id 2
Id 3
Id 4
```

Someone can explain this?

Comment: `foreach(...){...}` is a _flow control statement_ (ie. not a function barrier you can "return" from), as opposed to `%` (alias for `ForEach-Object`) which is a _command_

Answer (score -1):

Because `return` will exit the script/script block/function and returns the value. Here the issue is not with foreach, the output differs because of `return` key.

```
foreach ($id in $Ids) {

if ($Map[$id])
{
   $Map[$id]
} }
```

if you use the above code, the output will be the same as `%`

Comment: I think you missed the all point, return should stop the iteration! it's just do it when using `%` !!